# Power automate concatenate different columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I need to concatenate three columns, two of which are calculated when calculated. I cannot join them in a list validation way. I would need to know how to do it in power apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do it in Power Apps or in Power automate?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear as question title is saying you need solution using "Power Automate", but in question body you asked how to do it using "Power Apps".

Anyway, I will try to answer your question using both the ways.

**Using Power Apps**:

In Power Apps, you can use **Concatenate** function to concatenate multiple strings/columns.

**Example**: To show three column values in single label control, you can use formula like below in "Text" property of label control to (Assuming `ThisItem` is complete list item/record having all column values):

```
Concatenate(ThisItem.FirstName, " " , ThisItem.LastName, " is from Country: ", ThisItem.Country)
```

**OR**:

```
ThisItem.FirstName & " " & ThisItem.LastName & " is from Country: " & ThisItem.Country
```

**Documentation**: [Concat and Concatenate functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-concatenate)

---

**Using Power Automate**:

In Power automate, you can use `concat()` function in expression to concatenate multiple column values like:

```
concat('<text1>', '<text2>', '<text2>')
```

**Documentation**: [concat() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#concat)

Comment: You have to add column values in flow expression in place of `<text1>`, `<text2>`, etc. using **Dynamic content** pane. Make sure you are passing valid string in flow expression. Depending on column type you are using, you may need to convert them to a valid string first.

Comment: can you give me an example¨?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? Which column types are using? Which trigger/action outputs you are trying to concatenate? Edit your original question & add more details, attach screenshots if possible.,